# Blender Eevee (and cycles) not rendering White as pure white

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, color

So basically, I've rendered a scene, and it looked rather dull than what the viewport showed me. Not knowing what exactly caused the problem, I opened up a new blend file and checked to see if my base setup was free of this problem, turns out it wasn't.

[image]

[image]

Seems the white gets ever so slightly greyish and it's very very annoying. I don't know what could possibly be wrong.

Tried to reset my startup file, only to find out, my startup file was the default! What do I do!

[Blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/nrys3y3e7w1a4g1/Gray.blend/file)

Comment: Hi. In future, please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, Looked around and found out the solution. It was a color management problem. Under render properties > color management > view transform, it was set to "Filmic" when it should have been standard!!